# Targeting text within strong tags, purely via CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to switch off the div row-actions for the Woocommerce div in Wordpress only. Had a go with the code below but no joy. How can I target the adjacent div to Wooccomerce (wrapped in strong tags)

```
#the-list > tr.inactive > td.plugin-title.column-primary strong[title="WooCommerce"] > .row-actions visible {
display:none;
```

}

[image: DOM View of Divs]

Comment: That `strong` element doesn’t have any `title` attribute …

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the css adjacent(+) selector:

```
strong + .row-actions {...}
```